# Just want to redirect all know address of my site to specific file using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to redirect all the old url to my new url

My main reason behind this is admin will enter an address like this one
http://mysite.com/oil--gas/corrosion-management-summit-in-oil-and-gas!e29 on my site and i want to get this unknow address and redirect this address to specific file and get the url and search it from my database and redirect it to specific address .

old = http://mysite.com/oil--gas/corrosion-management-summit-in-oil-and-gas!e29

if user enter address like this i just want redirect this address to specific file like redirect.php and get query string from it so can anybody help me with this issue .

Comment: Have you searched for "pretty URLs" or "URL rewrite" at all? There's lots of information for this out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
# Redirect old file path to new file path
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```